# Cooliving or coliving? Are they the same? Any difference? What this the correct way to write it?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, writing

**Update**

After reading the comments, I think not everybody knows this word. Let me find a definition for you.

According with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-living, it means: Generally coliving is a type of intentional community that provides shared housing for people with similar values or intentions

**Original question:**

By searching on Google now both:

- "cooliving" About 82,700 results
- "coliving" About 3,080,000 results

So it seems coliving is preferred.

On the other hand, I've found this curious case:

[image: screenshot]

This suggest me that both are perfectly correct

May you give some light to the topic? Are they the same? Any difference? What this the correct way to write it?

Comment: What do you want it to mean? I’d think cooliving would be living cool.  I’d think coliving would be living together.

Comment: 'Cooliving' seems to be a whimsical play on the actual word 'coliving'. What do dictionaries say? Errors (and fanciful spellings) are often seen on the internet.

Comment: That would be _coolliving_. _Cooliving_ means sharing  an olive_

Comment: ... or living in a dovecote.

Comment: Despite my voting to close this question, I'm still glad it was asked. Where else would I find such priceless comments?

Comment: Guys, cooliving probably comes from cooperation. Anyway and according to your comments, it's quite clear you prefer using coliving instead (unless you want to share an olive which I don't recommend haha)

Comment: @chelder but but... cooperation is co-operation. I think that's why there's a second "o". And I want an olive.

Comment: @Rob so no idea why there are 82700 result in Google of cooliving!

Comment: Don't be distracted by one-off situations. Otherwise, if I write coooliving with 3 O's, some search result will show "that's one."

Comment: @YosefBaskin But doesn't "coooliving" mean a pigeon eating an olive and "cocoooliving" mean two pigeons sharing an olive? Good job John Cleese isn't here, he'd say it was getting silly.

Comment: I thought it was cool-living. From cooperation, really? [This question is about a typo].

Comment: The true number is [Page 5 of about **81 results**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cooliving%22&sxsrf=ALeKk01ObPjYxgk_C50NUwoQPfQLD-N6tw:1618090343178&ei=ZxlyYPWmCpq4sAfK5b_4Cg&start=80&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwi19vmg0PTvAhUaHOwKHcryD684PBDy0wN6BAgBEDs&biw=1309&bih=640) You must always click on the pages at the bottom of the webpage. Google gives out these astronomical figures  but if you check, you'll see the number of pages are only 10 or 12, when they should run into hundreds and thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps no matter how you look at it, to live together is co-living, which can be shortened to coliving, as per modern slang rules.

Prescriptively, the morpheme for "together as one" is co-, not coo-. The Florida Department of Education has a pretty comprehensive list of morphemes you can check out [here](http://www.fldoe.org/core/fileparse.php/16294/urlt/morphemeML.pdf).

descriptive linguistics, however, likes to talk about what people *are* saying and not what somebody says they should be saying. From a descriptive linguistics point of view, you should almost certainly say the one people actually use: "co-living" or "coliving"

while removing a hyphen is acceptable in slang (although I cannot cite this outside of general experience), people who don't expect to read the term "co-living" will often start reading "coliving" as [cɑlɪvɪŋ], due to the prescriptive spelling rules in English. This will confuse your audience, so for any formal situations where clarity is important, I would recommend the hyphen.

Additionally, if one googles "cooliving" you will get things about cool living. This makes more sense, and most people would recognize this portmantau very quickly. Not so much with cooliving, because it's not a portmanteau, it's a word with a morpheme in it, and an extra o. The only reason anybody could come up with cooliving would probably be taking the begining of "co-op" (or more likely "coop") and not realizing that the morpheme is co- and that the second o comes from the word "operate".

links often use mispelled words so they are easier to remember, puns, or simply because the original word was taking. In this case, cooliving.com is not about co-living at all. It's about living healthy and eco-friendly. it so happens that we are co-living on the planet together, but really their mission is to let us live cool; and to stop global warming.

Answer (score 4):

The number of Google hits is almost meaningless. Such hits contain repetitions, advertisements, typing mistakes, company names, etc.

Using this standard, there are 195 hits for coooliving and 4 hits for cooooliving! Does that make them proper words?

---

Instead, use [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=coliving%2Ccooliving%2Cco-living%2Cco-oliving%2Ccoo-living&year_start=1910&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)  You can see that in publications, *co-living* is most popular with *coliving* second. The other versions **do not appear at all**.

[image]